# Make special organic procedural texture

Tags: texturing, displacement, procedural

I have some problem to make this organic displacement texture
I want make it with procedural generator of blender, but I don't know if is possible.

[[image]][image]

My example which comes closest to it :

[image]

if anyone has an idea, or a different technique, thanks in advance!

Comment: Hello :). Just to keep this question focused, what specifically aren't you happy with? What do you want to improve?

Comment: We see in the example that the folds are more reinforced, blistered, the cavities more hollow.
It looks more like wrinkles, or bulges.
I'm not trying to get close to this result, I want exactly the same :)

Answer (score 16):

I ended up finding something that comes close !

Here is my procedure :

1.Add a cube.

2.Add this modifier :

[image][image]

First displace texture is for animating, add empty for focus coordinates object :

[image]

The second and third displace texture are the same :

[image]

And Enjoy the result !

[image]

For render i advise a lot of subsurface.